# My print statement will only print multiples of 10 and not in between

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a game board, but the x axis(the columns) will only print 0 -9 if the number is divisable by 10.

I am able to get the multiples of ten printed(10, 20, ...etc.)  and numbers less than ten(0-9). But any numbers between the tens won't print for the last multiple of ten. i.e. x= 15 prints 0123456789

```
import random

def getHSpace(xMax):
    hspace = ' '*3
    if xMax >= 10: # print 10+
        print(hspace + ('0123456789' * int(xMax/10)))#<--is there a 
                                                         better way
    else: # print 0-9
        for i in range(0, int(xMax)):
            hspace+=str(i)
        print(hspace)

getHSpace(15)
```

It should print all the numbers until the end of the board. 
i.e. x=15 should print  012345678901234

Comment: could you include what you want exactly and what you are getting right now in a code block? It's not very clear with sentences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modulo operator `%` is useful for these situations - it stands for "remainder after division". So, `66 % 10 = 6`, or `73 % 12 = 1`, or `21 % 7 = 0`.

In your particular case, you can use it to make a bunch of row headers, individually, and then join them together:

```
def getHSpace(xMax):
    return "   " + ''.join(str(i % 10) for i in range(xMax))
```

This produces `str(i % 10)` (that is, a one-digit number but as a string) for every number between `0` inclusive and `xMax` exclusive. Then, it joins them together using the empty string as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

According to this print:

`print(hspace + ('0123456789' * int(xMax/10)))`

when 10 <= xMax < 20, `int(xMax/10)` will be equal to 1, that's why your print is showing '0123456789' once, when you try xMax >= 20, you will get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do modulo (%).

```
def getHSpace(xMax):
    hspace = ' '*3
    num='0123456789'
    if xMax >= 10: # print 10+
        print(hspace + (num * int(xMax/10)) + num[:xMax%10])

    else: # print 0-9
        for i in range(0, int(xMax)):
            hspace+=str(i)
        print(hspace)
```